# Why did all the supported locales disappear in intl except for en?

Tags: php

I updated php version to 8.1.11 and got a problem with intl.

I use:

```php
ResourceBundle::getLocales('');
```

and after updating this method returns only en locales:

[image]

My environment:

- PHP Version 8.1.11
- intl: 71.1
- Docker: FROM php:8.1.11-fpm-alpine

[image]
[image]

where did all the locales go?

Comment: Did you build PHP yourself or use prebuilt binaries?

Comment: all with docker, do you think this is a bug in the build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue should happen for anyone who had installed `icu-libs` in the previous version and updated Alpine to 3.16 or above.

From the documentation:

> ICU data split The icu package has been split into:
>
> icu-data-en (2.6 MiB) - Stripped down ICU data with only en_US/GB
> locale and no legacy charset converters.
>
> icu-data-full (29 MiB) - Full
> ICU data. icu-libs only installs icu-data-en. If additional language
> support is required, icu-data-full needs to be installed manually.

So, we should have to add another apk to the Dockerfile to have full locales.

Answer (score 0):

this is due to the update of alpine.

I found a mention of it:
https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/samples/dotnetapp/Dockerfile.alpine-x64#L25

this solves the problem.

Comment: Please add the actual answer to your answer instead of linking to it.